# SQL: Chaining Joins Efficiency

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I have a query in my WordPress plugin like this:

```
SELECT users.*, U.`meta_value` AS first_name,M.`meta_value` AS last_name 
    FROM `nwp_users` AS users 
        LEFT JOIN `nwp_usermeta` U 
            ON users.`ID`=U.`user_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `nwp_usermeta` M 
            ON users.`ID`=M.`user_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `nwp_usermeta` C 
            ON users.`ID`=C.`user_id` 
    WHERE U.meta_key = 'first_name' 
        AND M.meta_key = 'last_name' 
        AND C.meta_key = 'nwp_capabilities' 
    ORDER BY users.`user_login` ASC 
    LIMIT 0,10
```

I'm new to using `JOIN` and I'm wondering how efficient it is to use so many `JOIN` in one query. Is it better to split it up into multiple queries?

[The database schema can be found here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_users)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JOIN` usually isn't so bad if the keys are indexed. `LEFT JOIN` is almost always a performance hit and you should avoid it if possible. The difference is that `LEFT JOIN` will join all rows in the joined table even if the column you're joining is NULL. While a regular (straight) `JOIN` just joins the rows that match.

Post your table structure and we can give you a better query.

Comment: In this case, the table I'm joining will always have a row that matches my criteria. But if regular JOIN is faster I'll use that. If you're interested, this is a vanilla WordPress installation so the table schema is listed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

Comment: JOIN will definitely be faster even if there are matches for everything. Your query is fine, just change LEFT JOIN to JOIN. Then make sure your the user_id and your ID fields in the various tables have an index on them. Take @MatejB's advice to use EXPLAIN to analyze the query.

Answer (score 2):

See this comment:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,205080,205274#msg-205274

For what it's worth, to find out what MySQL is doing and to see if you have indexed properly, always check the **EXPLAIN** plan.  You do this by putting EXPLAIN before your query (literally add the word EXPLAIN before the query), then run it.

In your query, you have a filter `AND C.meta_key = 'nwp_capabilities'` which means that all the LEFT JOINs above it can be equally written as INNER JOINs.  Because if the LEFT JOINS fail (LEFT OUTER is intended to preserve the results from the left side), the result will 100% be filtered out by the WHERE clause.

So a **more optimal** query would be

```
SELECT users.*, U.`meta_value` AS first_name,M.`meta_value` AS last_name 
    FROM `nwp_users` AS users 
        JOIN `nwp_usermeta` U 
            ON users.`ID`=U.`user_id` 
        JOIN `nwp_usermeta` M 
            ON users.`ID`=M.`user_id` 
        JOIN `nwp_usermeta` C 
            ON users.`ID`=C.`user_id` 
    WHERE U.meta_key = 'first_name' 
        AND M.meta_key = 'last_name' 
        AND C.meta_key = 'nwp_capabilities' 
    ORDER BY users.`user_login` ASC 
    LIMIT 0,10
```

(note: "JOIN" (alone) = "INNER JOIN")

Answer (score 1):

Try explaining the query to see what is going on and if your select if optimized. If you haven't used explain before read some tutorials:

http://www.learn-mysql-tutorial.com/OptimizeQueries.cfm

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm