# list results in mysql from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can i list the iduser from this table where gender=man and int=woman?

```
Table usermeta
----------------------
id  iduser a        b
12  204    age      19
7   203    age      35
6   200    age      24
3   201    age      34
5   201    gender   man
2   200    gender   woman
8   203    gender   man
9   204    gender   man
4   201    int      woman
10  204    int      male
11  203    int      woman
1   200    int      male
```

The answer should be:

iduser

204

I have another question, what if i want filter the age too?
I'am trying to resolve this but i can't...
Where shopuld i put the "age=19"?
I try this...
a.`a` = 'age'
AND a.`b` = '19'
but dont work...
thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should probably change your table structure.

Comment: hi, i can't change the structure of the table, is a usermeta table from wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join should work. Someting like (untested):

```
SELECT a.`iduser` FROM `table` a 
JOIN `table` b ON b.`iduser` = a.`iduser` 
WHERE a.`a`='gender' AND a.`b`='man' AND b.`a`='int' AND b.`b`='woman'
```

But you should consider to optimize the db structure since this seems a little performace hungry.

Comment: All those backticks make my head hurt. Not to mention the fact that you're not consistent with them AND they are completely unneeded.

Comment: Almost...but the `JOIN` needs to come before the `WHERE`.

Comment: -1, because the query does not answer the question and because it's a syntax error.

Comment: i can't change the structure of the table, is a usermeta table from wordpress.

Comment: @user919943: If you search for wordpress and usermeta, you'll find a lot of similar questions in the site. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959610/sql-chaining-joins-efficiency

Comment: @Johan why it didn't answer the question? It works, i tested it. And the syntax error is corrected, now.

Comment: @Johni: You need: `SELECT a.iduser`

Comment: @ypercube, `DISTINCT a.iduser` to be exact.

Comment: @Johan Since i don't think a user would have two gender or int, distinct isn't needed. I don't think its a good idea to add unnecessary processing time.

Comment: @Johni: I thought that too, but I checked and there is no such constraint in the wordpress db schema. So, Johan is correct.

Comment: I have another question, what if i want filter the age too? I'am trying to resolve this but i can't... Where shopuld i put the "age=19"? I try this... a.a = 'age' AND a.b = '19' but dont work... thanks.

Comment: @user91: you need another JOIN: `JOIN table c ON c.iduser=a.iduser` and then add the conditions for that table (with alias `c`).

Answer (score 1):

Yikes!

This is not how a database is supposed to look like, anyway.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.iduser FROM usermeta t1
INNER JOIN usermeta t2 ON (t1.iduser = t2.iduser)
WHERE t1.a = 'gender' AND t1.b = 'man'
      AND t2.a = 'int' AND t2.b = 'woman'
```

Comment: It is (yikes) EAV, but you don't need `DISTINCT` (I think).

Comment: @ypercube, not in the example data, but that might change if you insert more rows, in fact I think it outputs 2 rows in the example already.

Comment: You are right, I thought that `(iduser, a, b)` is unique (as in the example) but there is no such constraint in the worpress db schema.

Comment: this query work for me.
SELECT a.`iduser`
FROM `sqlin` a
JOIN `sqlin` b ON b.`iduser` = a.`iduser`
WHERE a.`a` = 'gender'
AND a.`b` = 'man'
AND b.`a` = 'int'
AND b.`b` = 'woman'

thanks!!